# How to open maganic popup opens every 15 seconds on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using JavaScript code on my webpage but it is appears only 2 times after 10 seconds, I want to display popup on every 15 seconds like to say infinite times, please help me out this, I am unable to find the solution for this, here the JavaScript code:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: 'Contact_Form/index.html'
            },
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

One more thing, if anyone click on my webpage, this popup appears, how can we do that, anyone there sort out my issue, I am not getting idea to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout`. That will repeat after the specified period of time infinitely.

```
function alertUser() {
  alert("Hello");
}

//This will run on page load
alertUser();

//This will wait 1000ms/1s first and then run the function and will repeat infinitely
setInterval(alertUser(), 1000);
```

## Edit:

To answer your question in the comment, simply use:

```
window.addEventLister("onclick", alertUser());
```

Comment: thanks its working but i want same popup display, if anyone click anywhere in my webpage.

Comment: I have added this, @santoshpatnaik

Answer (score 0):

### Here is my example code

- This part mention body of the web page.

  ```
  <body onclick="my()">

  </body>
  ```
- In script tags I used this part to display the **Popup** when click body of the page.

  ```
  if (onclick = "my()") {
    function my(){
      setTimeout(() => {
          alert("Hello world");
      }, ); 
    }
  }
  ```
- Secondly use this part in script tags also to display the **Popup** automatically after 3 second (*Every 3 second after popup will appear and i get 3 second as example you can use your own time*)

---

```
window.onload = function (){
   setInterval(() => {
       alert("Hello world");
   }, 3000);  
}
```

Here is the full code......

```
<body onclick="my()">

</body>

<script>
    if (onclick = "my()") {
      function my(){
         setTimeout(() => {
            alert("Hello world");
         }, ); 
      }
    }
    window.onload = function (){
      setInterval(() => {
        alert("Hello world");
      }, 3000);  
    }  
</script>
```

> Importent :- **Window.onload** function we can use to perform some task as
>   soon as the page finishes loading

**Copy and past to your editor and enjoy and i think you can get idea from this**

Comment: Thank you for your help, its really help me